# Show Azure DevOps Task / Sprint Statistics on SharePoint (PowerApps)

Tags: sharepoint, tfs, azure-devops, powerapps, powerapps-canvas

I want to show **KPIs** (Key Performance Indicator) on my SharePoint. My Datasource will be my TFS (Azure DevOps). For example showing the planned and finished Tasks for a Sprint on SharePoint and generate a graph out of it.

I saw that in Microsoft PowerApps - which are integrateable in my SharePoint-View - there are DevOps-Connectors, but i didnt rly saw a possibility to aggregate my task-statistics (planned / finished in a sprint) and show them.

**Solution**

Writing a C#-Backend that has a TFS-Client running.

1. Can I use this for a Power-App-CustomConnector?
2. Is there another way to acess data in a PowerApp from a REST-API?
3. Worst Case the Backend will have shedule to create and update SharePoint-Tables with my TFS-Stats

What is the best way to aggregate and show my tfs (azure devOps) statistics on my sharepoint page?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd recommend using Power BI, I use it for my Azure DevOps KPIs. You should be able to embed your Power BI reports within SharePoint easily. Power BI has ready-made connectors for aggregating work item data via the new Analytics Views preview feature. You'll want to start by enabling it within your **Preview Features:**

[image: Azure DevOps - Analytics Views]

Once you have the feature enabled, create an analytics view that aggregates the data you'll use in Power BI (or use a default view):

- **Creating an Analytics View:** https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/report/powerbi/analytics-views-create?view=azure-devops

After that, go ahead and open Power BI to connect to your Analytics View and start composing your KPI dashboard:

- **Create a Power BI report with a default Analytics view:** https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/report/powerbi/create-quick-report?view=azure-devops

After you've finished your report, embed it within SharePoint:

- **Power BI - Embed a Report in SharePoint:** https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/collaborate-share/service-embed-report-spo

Comment: Will do this and report to u!

Comment: Do all Users need a Premium Account to see embedded PowerBI in sharepoint?

Comment: Only the author needs to have a Pro account to share the report with Free Power BI users. You can find the documentation on how to share with free users here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/collaborate-share/service-embed-report-spo#grant-access-to-reports

Comment: Hey i dont think there is a solution with one poro license at least not for sharepoint embedded solutions - but thanks anyway